# Browse multiple image simultaneously in Magento

Tags: image, magento, upload

I want to upload multiple image in one time.

Please suggest code for browse multiple image & upload it simultaneously in Magento-----------

Comment: If you are doing it on admin side than you can use magento default image uploader with multiple files option.check Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader for detail.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Magento are you on?
How are you trying to upload?

We use EE and have always had the option in product configuration to upload multiple product images.

Catalog/Manage Products/

Select the appropriate product
Images/Browse Files

Select what you want upload

Upload Files/Save or Save and Continue Edit

Depending on how your store is setup you may need to reindex and flush your cache.